# Repeat Forever a If Function

Tags: c#, repeat

I'm developing a simple project, but how I can do a repeat forever a If function(It's like a command-line)? Thanks.

My code is like this:

```
Console.Write("> ");
var Command = Console.ReadLine();
if (Command == "About") {
    Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#");
    Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you already have?

Comment: Watch out, `forever` is `"a long time"` :-) – mjv 0 secs ago

Comment: By the way, `build` should really be `built`.

Comment: Also, `Operational` should probably be `Operating`.

Comment: Actually I think `Operational System` and `OS` should probably be `shell`.

Comment: Yes it will be a shell and thatnks for the correction ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string Command;
while (true) {
  Command = Console.ReadLine();
  if (Command == "About") {
    Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#");
    Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

By any chance do you mean:

```
while( !(!(!(( (true != false) && (false != true) ) || ( (true == true) || (false == false) )))) == false   )
   {
       Console.Write("> ");
       if ("About" == Console.ReadLine())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#");
           Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
       }
   }
```

Comment: I laughed while I was writing it

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear, but you probably want to do something like this:

```
while(true) {    //Loop forever
    string command = Console.ReadLine();
    if (command.Equals("Exit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        break;    //Get out of the infinite loop
    else if (command.Equals("About", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {A
        Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#");
        Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
while(true) {
    if( ...) {
    }
}
```

PS: this is one of my favourite preprocessor hacks. Doesn't work in C# though, only C/C++.

```
#define ever (;;)

for ever {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your question is really clear. But here is an attempt :)

```
while (true) {
   if (i ==j ) {
     // whatever
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an 'if' statement by itself because when it gets to the end your program will continue executing the next statement in your code. I think what you're after is a 'while' statement that always evaluates to true.

e.g.

```
string Command; 
while(true)
{
    Command = Console.ReadLine(); 
    if (Command == "About")
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
    }
}
```

This loop will be inescapable unless an exception is thrown or you execute a break statement (or whatever the equivalent is in C#, I'm a Java guy - don't hate me).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a simple `while` loop with (at least) one exit point.

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("> ");
    var command = Console.ReadLine();
    if (command == "about") {
        Console.WriteLine("This Operational System was build with Cosmos using C#");
        Console.WriteLine("Emerald OS v0.01");
    } else if (command == "exit") {
        break; // Exit loop
    }
}
```